# Jenkins logs in Master-Slave architecture

Tags: logging, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins and in the builds using groovy script to execute jobs. Instead of using Jenkins loggers, planning to write own loggers using 
Java logger or log4j. And we are having master-slave architecture.

As per my initial investigation, i can implement own logger and the log files can be stored in workspace, so that logs can be accessed via Web URL.
But i couldn't find any solution for the master-slave architecture, because log files will get stored in slave machine and i can transfer the log file after completion of the job only. I can't see the logs until the job gets finished.

Want to know how Jenkins implementaion in this scenario, so that will try to implement the same in my scenario.

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Comment: I don't understand your use case. You need access to the log before the job is complete? Then update your job workflow. There's really no point in shipping the agent logs to the master until the job is complete.

Comment: In the Jenkins, when a job is running in Slave machine, we can see the logs  from the browser.So, want to implement similar thing in Jenkins for own loggers.